# Which book in Asimov's Foundation series describes a video communication system just like our "Zoom"

Tags: story-identification, foundation

Long ago I read all the books in Asimov's *Foundation* series. In one of them, people are living alone or very few at a time on separate worlds that are far apart. They communicate via a video system that I remember as being very much like today's "Zoom." I can't find which book that is in. Can anyone help?

Comment: It could also be [*The Naked Sun*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Naked_Sun), but that too is from the Robot series instead of the Foundation series.

Comment: @user14111 Based on people living alone, I would have said *The Naked Sun* (thinking of Solaria) myself.  I agree it _wasn't_ part of the *Foundation* series, but I don't have modern copies, so I don't know how it's branded after the merging of the *Robots* series with *Foundation* to make a unified future history.

Comment: A public "visiphone" was used in Foundation. Is that similar enough to Zoom?

Comment: Note that videophones of various sorts have been a staple of futurology since Bell's time. E.g. https://www.dailymail.co.uk/sciencetech/article-2665946/From-FaceTime-smart-cookers-Postcards-reveal-19th-century-artists-predicted-world-look-like-today.html

Comment: Actually I remember a Mark Twain story about an inventor and their video phone device, and Mark Twain died in 1910.

Comment: What do you mean the robot stories are not part of the Foundation series?  Isaac Asimov wrote a series of novels which tied together the robot series and the Foundation series into a larger series, so they are all one series.

Comment: The question sort of reminds me of E.M. Forster's "The Machine Stops" (1909), though the people lived isolated lives in separate apartments in underground cities, communicating by video phones. http://www.visbox.com/prajlich/forster.html   http://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?41186

Comment: Germany had a working public videophone system in the 1930s (although that was within the post office rather than a personal system), so video conferencing was at that point not really science fiction anymore.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Possibly ["Mother Earth"](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?56133), a novelette in [Isaac Asimov](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isaac_Asimov)'s [*Positronic Robots*](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/pe.cgi?647) series which, for reasons unknown, Asimov later merged with his [*Foundation*](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/pe.cgi?11826) series; first published in [*Astounding Science Fiction*, May 1949](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/pl.cgi?57596). available at the [Internet Archive](https://archive.org/details/Astounding_v43n03_1949-05_cape1736/page/n58/mode/1up). (Asimov's "Mother Earth" was also the answer to the question [Short sci-fi story about Earth blockaded by other human colonies](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/105786/short-sci-fi-story-about-earth-blockaded-by-other-human-colonies).)

> Take the home of Franklin Maynard, for instance, who, with his wife, three children, and twenty-seven robots lived on an estate more than forty miles away, in distance, from the nearest neighbor. Yet by community-wave he could, if he wished, share the living room of any of the seventy-five million on Aurora—with each singly; with all simultaneously.
>
> Maynard knew every inch of his valley. He knew just where it ended, sharply, and gave way to the alien crags, along whose undesirable slopes the angular, sharp leaves of the native furze clung sullenly—as if in hatred of the softer matter that had usurped its place in the sun.
>
> Maynard did not have to leave that valley. He was a deputy in the Gathering, and a member of the Foreign Agents Committee, but he could transact all business, but the most extremely essential, by community-wave, without ever sacrificing that precious privacy he had to have in a way no Earthman could understand.
>
> Even the present business could be performed by community-wave. The man, for instance, who sat with him in his living room, was Charles Hijkman, and he, actually, was sitting in his own living room on an island in an artificial lake stocked with fifty varieties of fish, which happened to be twenty-five hundred miles distant, in space.
>
> The connection was an illusion, of course. If Maynard were to reach out a hand, he could feel the invisible wall.
>
> Even the robots were quite accustomed to the paradox, and when Hijkman raised a hand for a cigarette, Maynard's robots made no move to satisfy the desire, though a half-minute passed before Hijkman's own robot could do so.

Answer (score 7):

The story identification **answer** is in the comments to the question. The story is no doubt [The Naked Sun](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Naked_Sun), book two of the "Robot Novels". The confusing part of the question is "on separate worlds that are far apart". I think that is just the OP misremembering the story. On Solaria, the planet in the book, there were just a few people living there very far apart on very large estates. They were so far apart for so long that it was taboo to actually see or **gasp** touch anyone else in person.

Here is a spoiler filled link to how and why the "Robot Novels" were linked to "Foundation Novels".

[When did Asimov decide to unify the Foundation and Robots series?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/110786/when-did-asimov-decide-to-unify-the-foundation-and-robots-series)

Comment: If this is correct then [these](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/138878/story-novel-about-a-planet-where-people-interact-only-through-screens) [four](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/69097/book-about-a-world-whose-citizens-only-communicated-by-hologram) [questions](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/17593/name-of-the-sci-fi-book-where-all-human-contact-is-via-video-link) [are](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/224963/story-about-the-scientists-in-mars-that-are-less-cooperative-than-the-scientists) all potential duplicates, though only one has an accepted answer

Comment: But in The Naked Sun they communicate through 3D holograms. Zoom hasn't added support for those yet ;)

Answer (score 6):

I wanted to write a comment, but I fear it could be somehow a spoiler (for somebody who still needs to start the Foundation series).
The book is Foundation's Edge:

> The second Foundation use of mentalics to communicate with each other, in chapter 48*, is described as very similar to a video call: Gendibal (a Second Foundation Speaker) can speak to another member of the second Foundation through the mind, and the description evidences the shaping of an image of the interlocutor, even with some "artifacts" in the image itself (because of lack of concentration)!
>
>  *hoping that the chapters are the same in all editions of the novel...